# нужно по данному номеру года определять которой половины какого века

Tags: javascript

нужно по данному номеру года Y> = 0 определять которой половины X какого века C и какого тысячелетия M этот год положено по Григорианскому календарю

```js
let task06Btn = document.getElementById("task06Btn");
let task06Result = document.getElementById("task06Result");
task06Btn.addEventListener("click", function () {
  let year = document.getElementById('yeartovek').value;
  let s8 = 'век:';

  if (year % 100 > 0) {
    if (year % 100 >= 50) {
      task06Result.innerHTML = `${s8}${Math.round(year / 100)}`;
    } else {
      task06Result.innerHTML = `${s8}${(Math.round((year / 100)) + 1)}`;
    }
  } else {
    task06Result.innerHTML = `${s8}${Math.round((year / 100) + 1)}`;
  }
});
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Год в век</td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" id="yeartovek" placeholder="рік">
      <button id="task06Btn">Go</button>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div id="task06Result"></div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Как реализовать поиск "какая половина века" и год положено по Григорианскому календарю

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
function fun(year) {
  return {
    "половина века": 1 + ((year % 100) > 50),
    "век": 1 + Math.trunc(year/100),
    "тысячелетие": 1 + Math.trunc(year/1000)
  };
}

console.log(2020, fun(2020));
console.log(1990, fun(1990));
console.log(2169, fun(2169));
```

Ключи объекта просто для наглядности